# Cakephp virtual field if this column empty use this column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a table named "Contacts" and I would like to create a virtual field called customer.

Contacts has column, called first_name, last_name, company.

I got it to work creating virtual field by concatenate all three

```
public $virtualFields = array(
'customer' => "CONCAT(Contact.first_name, ' ', Contact.last_name, ' ', Contact.company)"        
);
```

but how can I create it so it instead just show the company, but if it's null or empty string, it will show the first name and last name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try putting an SQL IF statement into it:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
'customer' => "IF(Contact.company IS NULL OR Contact.company = '', CONCAT(Contact.first_name, ' ', Contact.last_name, ' ', Contact.company), Contact.company)"
);
```

As far as `is null or is empty` goes, does your database not have a consistent empty value? If it doesn't, it should and you should address it...

Comment: I'm sorry, my database is set to default value None. How should I approach this? what should I put in company IS NULL?

Comment: That if statement above is saying "if company is null then concatenate the names together, otherwise use company". If your db default value is none, you should set it to nullable default null for consistency

Comment: Have updated my answer to include the blank case. Let me know if it works!